# Justification of Poisson postulates

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

This may be a dumb question.

The Poisson postulates are:

1. $P(n=1,h) = \lambda h + o(h)$
2. $\sum\limits_{i=2}^{\infty}P(n=i,h) = o(h)$
3. Events in nonoverlapping intervals are independent

What ensures that $\lambda h \in [0,1]$ irrespective of the value of $\lambda$ ?

Comment: Being WYSIWYG, are you sure about $Possion$ ?

Comment: I am sorry.. it was a typo.. but somehow I made it twice!! Thanks for the subtle hint..

Comment: Don't be sorry at all ! It was funny because of your name !! Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What ensures that $\lambda h \in [0,1]$ irrespective of the value of $\lambda$ ?

Nothing does, and this is not what these conditions say. Condition 1. should read 
$$
P(N_h=1)=\lambda h+o(h),
$$
which means
$$
\lim\limits_{h\to0+}\frac{P(N_h=1)}h=\lambda.
$$
Note that $O(h)$ should read $o(h)$ and that the condition is only concerned with the limit when $h\to0+$.

Likewise, condition 2. should read 
$$
P(N_h\geqslant2)=o(h),
$$
which means
$$
\lim\limits_{h\to0+}\frac{P(N_h\geqslant2)}h=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you.. I forgot to mention the limits. But they never explain like this in any textbook that I referred.

Comment: Just a clarification: So it means that in an infinitesimally short interval the rate of change of probability would be equal to macroscopic rate ?.... Another dumb query- is $O(h)$ technically different from $o(h)$, or is it always the latter.

Comment: A homogenous Poisson process has a constant rate of change, often called its intensity and denoted $\lambda$. // $O(h)$ denotes the class of functions $f:h\mapsto f(h)$ *controlled* by $h$ when $h\to0$, in the sense that there exists $h_0$ et $C$ such that $|f(h)|\leqslant C|h|$ for every $|h|\leqslant h_0$. Equivalently, $\limsup\limits_{h\to0}|f(h)|/|h|$ is finite. // $o(h)$ denotes the class of functions *vanishingly small* with respect to $h$ when $h\to0$, in the sense that $\lim\limits_{h\to0}f(h)/h=0$. // Thus $o(h)\subset O(h)$ and the function $h\mapsto h$ is in $O(h)\setminus o(h)$.